# run a Linux/windows command in agularjs using eclipse

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, eclipse

I am hosting a webpage using eclipse with html and angularjs on an apache server. The UI will take few inputs from user and save it in JSON format in a JSON file.

After this is done, I want to execute a command once the user clicks on submit button.

Can someone please help me as to how can I run a command in angularjs. It would be really helpful if you could tell me how this can be done on both Linux and Windows operating systems.

Comment: Please paste your code, tell us what you have tried, and what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to run a shell script or a Linux command with angular. What you can basically do is set up a RESTFul service, which takes the command you want to execute and pass it your backend service. There could arise some complications even if you achieve this. You should maintain permissions restricting users to run commands as super users.

If you are using java, take a look at ProcessBuilder which will help you execute your Linux command.

Answer (score 0):

You have the write the JSON manupulation code inside the event of the submit button click function. Declare a function for submit button click, then in that function take those input parameter from the DOM and then create JSON object. It is not about any command.